# use llvm to implement a arm disassembler

Tags: llvm, disassembly

recently, i want to analyze some library which in android.
but arm assembler is hardly to understand,so i want to use llvm to implement a disassembler
i find a document about this topic at here:http://llvm.org/docs/MarkedUpDisassembly.html#instruction-annotations
and a cpp file at here http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/ARMDisassembler_8cpp_source.html
and then use some rules to translate assembler code to c code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing within LLVM that will help you translate assembly to C code. The disassembly capabilities LLVM provides can disassemble machine code (binaries) for the targets it supports to assembly.

Moreover, if you're finding the assembly hard to understand, I should say that you probably won't understand the resulting C code. C code created by decompilation tools (the usual name for converting assembly to C) isn't very readable and you must have a strong knowledge of assembly language to understand it anyway.

Comment: sorry,maybe i can't express my opinion clear. I want to use LLVM to disassemble arm binary and then use my rule to translate assembly to c code.I have some rule can help me to translate assembly to c code,just use LLVM to disassemble arm binary.

Comment: @tfzxyinhao: if you want to use LLVM for disassembling machine code into assembly, use the `llvm-mc` tool (for example read the description here - http://blog.llvm.org/2010/01/x86-disassembler.html)